# Upper bounds for $|\theta(x)-x|$ assuming Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

What are the best currently known upper bounds for $|\theta(x)-x|$ assuming the Riemann Hypothesis, where $\theta(x)$ is the Chebyshev theta, and can someone provide the reference for this (not Wikipidia, where it states bounds of $O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$, for any $\epsilon>0$ without a reference).

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on RH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Distribution_of_prime_numbers) has a precise bound for $|\psi(x)-x|$. Relation between $\psi(x)$ and $\theta(x)$ is elementary, see e.g. [here](http://www.unilim.fr/laco/rapports/1998/R1998_06.pdf) and references there.

Comment: There is also a result in Schoenfeld's "Sharper Bounds for the Chebyshev Functions $\theta(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ II", but is that currently the best ...?

Comment: I know that Pierre Dusart has some results going past that paper.  You might look at his papers, and then look at those who cite him to see if he still has the record.

Comment: Do you need explicit bounds, that is, with an explicit constant? Or do you want what is asymptotically best?

Comment: I am curious about both.  The Schoenfeld bound works well for what I am doing, but I was wondering whether there is something better, as you can then improve your results ... thanks all for comments

Answer (score 7):

$\vert\psi(x)-x\vert \leq \sqrt{x}\log^2x/(8\pi)$ is equivalent to RH.  See Theorem 4.9 of the book "Equivalents of the Riemann Hypothesis" by Broughan (2017).

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @Xiaolong Wu: What's the precise result you get for $|\vartheta(x)-x|$? Cf. https://mathoverflow.net/a/407661/1593