# Question about $\theta$ and the Riemann Hypthesis - reference request

Tags: reference-request, riemann-hypothesis

It is well known that the Riemann Hypothesis implies the following:

$|\theta(x) - x| = O(x^{1/2 + \epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

where $\theta$ is the first Chebyshev function; that is, $\theta(x)$ is the sum of the logs of all the primes up to $x$. Is it known whether the reverse implication holds? If so, could you please supply the reference? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More is true.  Let $c\in [1/2,1)$ be a constant.  It is well-known that the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros in the half plane $\Re(s)> c$ if and only if $|\theta(x)-x|=O(x^{c+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

You can find this proved in most texts on the Riemann zeta function, such as  Titchmarsh's book.

Comment: Thank you Pace, this is the kind of answer I was hoping for. I will accept it in a couple of days if no one has anything else to add.  Best, EGME

Comment: Which of the two Titchmarsh books on the Riemann zeta function would this be (year?) does the same hold fox $\psi$?

Answer (score 1):

I consider that you should take a look at chapter 4 of the first volume of "Equivalents of the Riemann Hypothesis" by Kevin Broughan. [Theorem 4.9](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108178228.006) in the book is **Schoenfeld's criterion**:

> The Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to the inequality $$|\psi(x)-x| \leq \frac{\sqrt{x}\log^{2} x}{8\pi}, \quad (x \geq 74)$$.

By combining this result and the fact that $\psi(x)-\vartheta(x) < 1.5 \, \sqrt{x}$ (for any $x>0$), it can be proven that, if $\displaystyle C \in \left(0, \frac{1}{8\pi}- \frac{1.5}{\log^{2} 74}\right]$ and $|\vartheta(x)-x| \leq C \sqrt{x} \log^{2}x$, then the Riemann Hypothesis holds.